# Display Image in ASP:Image from getting path from sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image

i am getting image urls path from sql.
now my code to display Image in asp.net asp:Image is

```
con = new SqlConnection(connect);
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select_performer_Gold";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Performance_Category", Performance_Category);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            goldimg1.ImageUrl = "User_Images/" + dr["User_image"].ToString();
            goldimg2.ImageUrl = "User_Images/" + dr["User_image"].ToString();
        }
```

problem is while loop runs 2 time as i have 2 rows in DB
so in 1st loop both the image urls are given 1st row Image path
and in 2nd loop both image urls are given 2nd row Image path
So only 2nd row User_Image are displayed in both goldimg1 and goldimg2.

How to display respective image in goldimg1 and goldimg2

Comment: Why do you have 2 rows for the image paths? Shouldn't it be in 2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better result you have to use `SqlDataAdapter`

First :retrns result in `Dataset`

then bind it with `goldimg1.ImageUrl`

Example:

```
goldimg1.ImageUrl=ds.Table[0].Rows[0]["User_image"].ToString();
goldimg2.ImageUrl=ds.Table[0].Rows[1]["User_image"].ToString();    //you can also use forech loop
```

Comment: please also provide code for foreach loop. i have 4 goldimg tags and if there is 2 rows in DB than exception come

Answer (score 0):

**This Code help you to get all the image path from database.**

before using of for loop you have to take `<image>` control in the `GridView` or `ListView`

```
 if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
    {
      for(int i=0;i<=ds.Rows.Count-1;i++)
         {
           goldimg1.ImageUrl=ds.Table[0].Rows[i]["User_image"].ToString();
         }
    }
```

Some Example:

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-save-images-into-folder-and.html
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/how-to-insert-images-into-database-and.html